# How to use server side variable in outer javascript

Tags: javascript, struts

Hello Every one I am recently joined to work with struts. Where there is a lot of javascript code in jsp page but ultimetely it cause performace issue when this website is viewed on small devices. So we are planned to move all those javascript into a single script file. But what problem I face is that there were lot of serverside variable in forms of el expression is not accessible in outer javascript file. Please provide me solutions if you have any.
Thanking you in advance

Comment: AFAIK the only solution is to create those variables in the jsp file and let the script file use those variables

Comment: The stand alone script file should not hold any state values, it should be passed to it

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, you may extract only the logic pieces into the external file, while preserving a small inline script for passing the variables.

As a very simplified example, you may extract from:

```
<script>
    alert(${helloWorld});
</script>
```

the following part into a separate file:

```
function sayHello(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

And keep the variables in an inline script:

```
<script>
    var helloWorld = ${helloWorld};
    sayHello(helloWorld);
</script>
```

This also encourages some separation of concerns which is a good design recommendation anyway. I am not diving into any other [good practices](https://www.google.ch/search?q=javascript%20good%20practices) such as the module pattern in this place.

Comment: I have thousands of such expression so should i define thousands of global variable also it is not certain that expression language have only string or int type result. I may have even object too..

Comment: @user: If you have thousands of *server variables* you can use a structure (an array or an object as in Sumurai8's answer) to pass in the data. If you use several server variables *thousands of times* in the JS code, you will need to replace them by parameters (such as `helloWorld` in the above example) which will be a much better JS code structure anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your external javascript file should be static. This will allow the client to cache it, and ultimately will make your site faster.

If you need function `x` to use custom data `y` and `z`, you can call it with `x( y, z );`. If you have larger datastructures, you can either dump them in the global scope between script-tags (see below) or, I think the better solution, load the larger datastructures via ajax.

```
<script>
  var data = { "a" : "b", "c" : "d", "e" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] };
</script>
```